# Uploading wide image returns blank

Tags: php, html

I want to display any image from users computer, but I only managed to save less wide images. When I go to upload an image with size of 4000x3000 it stops showing up and comes up as a question mark:(

Here's the code for 2 pages that upload and show an image.

Upload page:

```
<form action="e-mail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="picture" id="picture">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
     </form>
```

Show page:

```
    <?php 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE); 

session_start(); 
//set session

     $filename    = $_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"];
    $destination = "upload/" . $_FILES["picture"]["name"];  // Less wide imaged are save to "upload" whereas wider don't..

     move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination);

    $_SESSION['picture'] = $destination;

   ?> 
<html>
<head>

 <img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['picture']; ?>"/> // this code shows less wide images perfectly

</head>
  </html>
```

So my question is " how can I save wide images to "upload" folder?

Thanks:)

Comment: What is the filename of the wider image? And the filesize?

Answer (score 1):

You should read the part in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) about file uploads. There is some very important information there.

The gist of the issue is that there is a limit on the size of file uploads, set up in `php.ini` or in the server configuration. The default is 2 megabytes, and if your image is 3000x4000, that is 12,000,000 pixels, there is a good chance it's more than 2 megabytes (check its size on your disk).

If you need to upload such images, you have to change the `upload_max_filesize` setting on the server side (php.ini or Apache configuration).